# How to give name or tag for intermediate image?

Tags: java, docker

I used docker to build my Java application and I using the multi-stage building and I have some problems every time when I run the docker command for building the docker creates new intermediate image with tag and name `none` and I need the possibility to called intermediate containers.

That is my dockerfile:

```
FROM jdk8_201-ubuntu16.04 as java_build
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y dos2unix

ARG MVN_USER
ARG MVN_PASS
ARG GIT_BRANCH
ARG BUILD_ID
ARG COMMIT_ID
WORKDIR /tmp/app

COPY pom.xml /maven-build/pom.xml
COPY /.mvn/settings.xml /maven-build/settings.xml
COPY mvnw ./mvnw
COPY mvnw.cmd ./mvnw.cmd
COPY /.mvn ./.mvn

RUN chmod +x ./mvnw && \
./mvnw -s /maven-build/settings.xml -B -f /maven-build/pom.xml dependency:resolve dependency:resolve-plugins dependency:go-offline

COPY ./ ./

FROM ubuntu
...
```

and after each running `docker build` command I had a many `none` images:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              30e2325fcf15        18 hours ago        1.68GB
<none>              <none>              30e2325fcf16        18 hours ago        1.68GB
<none>              <none>              30e2325fcf14        18 hours ago        1.68GB
<none>              <none>              30e2325fcf18        18 hours ago        1.68GB
<none>              <none>              30e2325fcf13        18 hours ago        1.68GB
```

How can I replace `none` name of intermediate images to `my_image_name`?

Comment: `<none>              <none>              30e2325fcf15        18 hours ago        1.68GB` this does not seems intermediate layer but it seems the complete image which mark none after rebuild with same tag. all you need to specify different build name to avoid marking them `none`. or `ocker build -t "my_image$(date +%N)"  .`

Comment: @Adiii its intermediate container or something like this because if I leave only one section ```FROM``` in my dockerfile all is good no ```none``` images in docker.

Comment: @Adiii try to write ```dockerfile``` in a multistage format where located at least two ```FROM``` section and build it and after that run command ```docker images ls``` in the terminal and you'll see ```none``` images.

Comment: is there any specific need to tag them? you can set label to these intermediate image.

Comment: https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/

Comment: Or you can add a label to that image: https://forums.docker.com/t/tag-intermediate-build-stages-multi-stage-build/34795

Comment: Adding a label to the image will change the image, so then there will be a new intermediate builder created when building the Dockerfile. The correct answer is you cannot tag an intermediate image. I would consider the accepted answer below a workaround.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use `docker build -t image_name`  to tag the image.But intermediate images will have `<none>` as the image name.

`<none>` images are formed as part of the multistage builds. If there are multiple FROM in your dockerfile then building image will create multiple images along with `<none>` images which are intermediate images used by main image.

for example

dockerfile:

```
$ cat dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS compile-image
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc build-essential
WORKDIR /root
COPY . hello.c
RUN mkdir -p helloworld hello.c

FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS runtime-image
COPY --from=compile-image /root/helloworld .
CMD ["./helloworld"]
```

In the above dockerfile I am using ubuntu:18.04 as intermediate image which is used again in the **COPY** command above.
HERE `COPY --from=compile-image /root/helloworld .`

So When I build an image using above dockerfile by command

```
$ sudo docker build -t sample_image .
```

The above command will create two images as below.

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
sample_image        latest              32b62676d8b8        About a minute ago   64.2MB
<none>              <none>              dfb370218e54        About a minute ago   282MB
```

`<none>` is an intermediate image. which is again internally used in the dockerfile.

now the solution for your question would be creating two docker files and using them separately.

For example, the above dockerfile can be divided into two dockerfiles and can be used to create separate images without any intermediate image.

dockerfile 1:

```
$ sudo vi dockerfile
$ sudo cat dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS compile-image
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc build-essential
WORKDIR /root
COPY . hello.c
RUN mkdir -p helloworld hello.c
```

and execute
`$ sudo docker build -t compile_image .`

by changing docker file again

docker file 2:

```
$ sudo vi dockerfile
$ sudo cat dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY --from=compile_image /root/helloworld .
CMD ["./helloworld"]
```

and execute: `$ sudo docker build -t runtime_image .`

the output will not have intermediate images. Hence no `<none>` images.

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
compile_image       latest              b580efe23dad        About a minute ago   282MB
runtime_image       latest              32b62676d8b8        3 minutes ago        64.2MB
```

**FYI:** In second docker file, I used previously build image **compile_image** in **COPY** command

`COPY --from=compile_image /root/helloworld .`

Here compile_image acts like an intermediate image.

If you observe previous images the memory occupied by `<none>` and compile_image are same and sample_image and runtime_image are the same. The main purpose of using the multistage builds is to reduce the size of an image.

Comment: Thanks for your solution maybe it can be useful for me.

Comment: We used this method to cache the compile-image in Gitlab CI/CD

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `--target` keyword to build just a specific stage:

`docker build --target compile-image --tag compile-image:0.0.1 .`

Comment: The most elegant solution IMO.  Builder image will be tagged, and subsequent run of `docker build` without --target to produce the final image will use cached builder anyway.

Comment: This does what the OP (and me) wants I believe.

Answer (score 11):

This Docker forum [post suggest to use labels](https://forums.docker.com/t/tag-intermediate-build-stages-multi-stage-build/34795/2) as follows:

> For anyone that is interested in something similar, I’ve found a
> workaround for now.
>
> Using the `LABEL` command in my dockerfile I added a label to the build
> stage I’m interested in, then filter for it later:
>
> ```
> FROM node AS builder-stage
> LABEL builder=true
> ```
>
> ```
> FROM node AS app-stage
> LABEL builder=false
> ```
>
> Now to filter, sort newest first, cut out the date, and take the top
> row: `docker images --filter “label=builder=true” --format  ‘{{.CreatedAt}}\t{{.ID}}’ | sort -nr | head -n 1 | cut -f2`
>
> Note that it is important to remove the label in the next build stage.